# Test whether an integer is between two other integers

Tags: c#, integer

I search to test if an integer is between two other integers without use the "if" condition but with a specific method in c#.

Is it possible ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a extension method.

You must create a static class:

```
namespace Extension
{ 
static class MyIntMethods
  {
    public static bool Between(this int value,int min, int max)
    {
        return (value > min && value < max) ? true : false;
    }
  }
}
```

next step:
Add the name space in the class you want to use the new method:

```
using Extension;
```

And now use the new method:

```
int n1 = 1;
n2 = 2;
n3 = 3;

result = n2.Between(n1, n3);
```